# Pricing of $(S(T_0)-S(T))^+$

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-calculus, derivatives

> **Problem**: Consider a new derivative that at time $T$ pays $Y =(S(T_0) − S(T))^+$

> where
> $0 < T_0 < T$ is a fixed date.

> (i) Show that the arbitrage-free of Y at time $t = T_0$ is given by $\pi_{T_0}
> (Y ) =pS(T_0)$ where p is independent of the stock price.

> (ii) Determine the arbitrage-free price of derivative $Y$ at time $t < T_0$.

To value the contract I would use the Black-Scholes PDE solution $E^{Q}((S(T_0) − S(T))^+|\mathscr{F}_{T_{0}})=E^{Q}((S(T_0) − S(T)) \:1_{S(T_0\geqslant S(T))}|\mathscr{F}_{T_{0}})$

I know that $S(T_0)-S(T)$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_{T_0}$. But it is not independent of $1_{S(T_0\geqslant S(T))}$, so I cannot split them into two expected values. Even if I did, I would not get the result. I tried to solve using the exponential form of S(T) but got nowhere.

I though that when $t=T_0$ then $Y$ is a put option which implies that $E^{Q}((S(T_0) − S(T))^+|\mathscr{F}_{T_{0}})=S(T_0)(e^{T-T_0}\Phi(-d_2)-\Phi(-d_1))$ where d_2 and d_1 do not depend on the stock.

**Question:**

Is my solution correct?

How do I solve the second question when $t<T_0$? I think I cannot used a pre-defined result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At time $T_0$, the strike price becomes known and the option turns into a ``normal'' put option, i.e.
\begin{align*}
V(T_0,S_{T_0}) &= S_{T_0}e^{-r(T-T_0)}\Phi(-d_2)-S_{T_0}e^{-q(T-T_0)}\Phi(-d_1) \\
&= S_{T_0}\underbrace{\left(e^{-r(T-T_0)}\Phi(-d_2)-e^{-q(T-T_0)}\Phi(-d_1)\right),}_{=:p}
\end{align*}
where $p$ is indeed independent of the stock price because
\begin{align*}
d_{1,2}=\frac{r-q\pm\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}{\sigma}\sqrt{T-T_0}.
\end{align*}

---

In general, for $t> T_0$, the Black-Scholes formula is
\begin{align*}
V(t,S_t) &= S_{T_0}e^{-r(T-t)}\Phi(-d_2)-S_te^{-q(T-t)}\Phi(-d_1),
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
d_{1,2}=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{S_t}{S_{T_0}}\right)+\left(r-q\pm\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}.
\end{align*}
Of course, $\lim\limits_{t\downarrow T_0}V(t,S_t)=S_{T_0}p$.

---

For $t<T_0$, the option value is
\begin{align*}
V(t,S_t)&=e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_t\left[\max\{S_{T_0}-S_T,0\}\right] \\
&=e^{-r(T-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_t\left[\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_{T_0}\left[\max\{S_{T_0}-S_T,0\}\right]\right] \\
&=e^{-r(T_0-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_t\left[e^{-r(T-T_0)}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_{T_0}\left[\max\{S_{T_0}-S_T,0\}\right]\right]\\
&=e^{-r(T_0-t)}\mathbb{E}^\mathbb{Q}_t\left[S_{T_0}p\right] \\
&=pe^{-r(T_0-t)}S_te^{(r-q)(T_0-t)} \\
&=S_te^{-q(T_0-t)}\left(e^{-r(T-T_0)}\Phi(-d_2)-e^{-q(T-T_0)}\Phi(-d_1)\right).
\end{align*}
Of course, $\lim\limits_{t\uparrow T_0}V(t,S_t)=S_{T_0}p$.

Comment: In case of interest, this option is also pricable analytically under Heston stochastic vol, eg. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/34226925.pdf

Comment: As @StackG correctly adds, the option is pricable in closed form for many models with closed-form solution for European put options. To keep the calculations simple, we'd need $p$ to be independent of $S_{T_0}$. This applies to exponential Lévy processes (e.g. Merton and Kou's jump diffusion models as well as NIG, VG and CGMY) and stochastic volatility models (e.g. Heston or Grasselli's 4/2 model).